# UWP RichEditBox saveToStream utf-8 encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, uwp, richeditbox

I want to save a RichEditBox Document, so I call the loadFromStream method to load the file. But, when I try to save it with saveToStream method the text saved is not encoded in utf-8.

That's my code which saves the file :

`IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);                        richEditBox.Document.SaveToStream(TextGetOptions.None, stream);`

I have to encode this document in utf-8 because the text that I want to save is a script to launch and when I launch it, that raises an error saying that characters can't be read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the text of the richeditbox.

```
string str;
richEditBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out str);
```

Then save it with the encoding you want,

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream.AsStreamForWrite(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    await sw.WriteAsync(str);
}
```